# What's the DRYest way to replace a file with a symlink in bash

Tags: bash, dry

I have an existing file which I'm replacing with a symlink to another file.  So I basically need to do this:

```
rm orig
ln -s /var/better orig
```

I DRYed the above to this:

```
{rm,ln\ -s\ /var/better}\ orig\;
```

But it no longer works.  The shell now complains:

```
-bash: rm orig;: command not found
```

Is there a way to make the DRY form work?

Comment: Why not just put `orig` in a shell variable like `$ORIG`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use "-f".

```
ln -sf /var/better orig
```

From `man ln`

> -f, --force
>    remove existing destination files

Comment: I didn't realize -f also worked to remove regular files as well!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is cp:

```
cp -sf /var/better orig
```